# What kind of identity is this?

Tags: trigonometry, classical-mechanics

I have been trying to understand [this](http://www.madscitech.org/tm/slns/l5e2.pdf) problem from The Theoretical Minimum. The following solution is given for the equation of motion of a harmonic oscillator.
$$
\vec{r}(t)=\vec{c}_1\cos(\omega t)+\vec{c}_2\sin(\omega t)
$$
Its rewritten for a given angle $\theta$.
$$
\vec{r}(t)=\vec{b}_1\cos(\omega t - \theta)+\vec{b}_2\sin(\omega t - \theta)
$$
Where
$$
\vec{b}_1=\vec{c}_1\cos(\theta)+\vec{c}_2\sin(\theta)
$$
and
$$
\vec{b}_2=\vec{c}_2\cos(\theta)-\vec{c}_1\sin(\theta)
$$

I want to know what identity or trigonometric property is this.
Thanks.

Comment: It's an identity relating composition of two planar rotation matrices through angles $\theta$ and $\omega t - \theta$ with a rotation matrix through the sum of angles.

Comment: This follows from the trigonometric identities for sums and differences of angles (as arguments of sine and cosine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are exploiting the following identities:
[image: Trigonometric identity]

Use the last two on the equation:
$$\vec{r}(t)=\vec{b}_1\cos(\omega t - \theta) + \vec{b}_2\sin(\omega t - \theta)$$
expand it and then group identical terms of sine and cosine of $\omega t$, and you should reach the first version independent of $\theta$ (well, is just a constant so it still hiden into the other constants).